# GLIBCXX 3.4.14 missing for Garry's Mod on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, libraries, gcc

When installing Garry's Mod via Steam on my CentOS server I get the following errors:

--

> ConVarRef mat_dxlevel doesn't point to an existing ConVar
>   Game_srv.so loaded for "Garry's Mod"
>   Initializing Steam libraries for secure Internet server
>   SteamGameServer_InitSafe failed!
>
> ---
>
> Unable to load Steam support library.*
>   Unable to load Steam support library.*
>   This server will operate in LAN mode only.*
>   This server will operate in LAN mode only.*
>
> ---
>
> 1. failed to dlopen /home/tcagame/admin/1/garrysmod/bin/lua_shared_srv.so error=/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by bin/libsteam.so)
> 2. Couldn't locate library [lua_shared_srv] or couldn't find module [LUASHARED003]
> 3. Couldn't Load Library 'lua_shared_srv' (looking for interface LUASHARED003)Couldn't Load Library 'lua_shared_srv' (looking for interface LUASHARED003)

--

--

**All the libstdc++ library's are installed of up to date. I have installed the following list:**

1. compat-libstdc++-296.i686 : Compatibility 2.96-RH standard C++ libraries
2. compat-libstdc++-33.i686 : Compatibility standard C++ libraries
3. compat-libstdc++-33.x86_64 : Compatibility standard C++ libraries
4. libstdc++.i686 : GNU Standard C++ Library
5. libstdc++.x86_64 : GNU Standard C++ Library
6. libstdc++-devel.i686 : Header files and libraries for C++ development
7. libstdc++-devel.x86_64 : Header files and libraries for C++ development

--

--

***strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX* shows the following list where you can see .14 is missing:**

- GLIBCXX_3.4
- GLIBCXX_3.4.1
- GLIBCXX_3.4.2
- GLIBCXX_3.4.3
- GLIBCXX_3.4.4
- GLIBCXX_3.4.5
- GLIBCXX_3.4.6
- GLIBCXX_3.4.7
- GLIBCXX_3.4.8
- GLIBCXX_3.4.9
- GLIBCXX_3.4.10
- GLIBCXX_3.4.11
- GLIBCXX_3.4.12
- GLIBCXX_3.4.13
- GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
- GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how old this thread is, but I did find a working fix to this. I had the same problem, so on a hunch, I compiled a whole new system wide gcc. (4.8.2 in my case), and installed it to /usr

One of the gcc libraries in the build  I used fixed the problem. I'm not sure which one. So I recommend compiling the FULL gcc source. That's what i did and it seemed to work

if you are still having this issue,  try this fix. I'm no expert at this myself, but I hope this helps you. Sorry if I wasn't specific enough.